# Bit Manipulation for Values within Range

Tags: swift, operators, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, binary-operators

I have an option set with the 4 bit range indicated by the mask `applicationReserved = 0x0F000000`. From this, I would like to generate the possible values `0x01000000`, `0x02000000`, `0x03000000`, ...

I've come up with some possible solutions, but I suspect there may be a more clear expression than this:

```
applicationReserved & -applicationReserved
applicationReserved & -applicationReserved << 1
...
```

or

```
applicationReserved / 15
applicationReserved / 15 * 2 
...
```

Comment: a range must have a begin and an end. You only have one bound

Comment: I don't understand the problem, and I don't understand the solution. Given the set of possible values you seem to be describing do you mean that any `x` such that `(x & applicationReserved) != 0` is reserved? If so, what does "a solution" even mean - do you want to test for that condition? Generate them? What are you actually doing

Comment: In this particular instance, I think it's just assumed that it's a 4 bit range. `applicationReserved = 0x0F000000` represents `0x010000000 - 0x0F0000000`. Here's the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolevents/uicontroleventapplicationreserved?language=objc) for this specific implementation.

Comment: @harold I would like to generate them. Given `x = 0x0F000000` what is the simplest way to generate the values `0x01000000`, `0x02000000`, `0x03000000`

Comment: From that link it just seems like 4 bits are reserved for application use, and you can generate them as `x << 24` where `x in [0 .. 15]` (includes 0, because you can set all 4 reserved bits to zero). E: you can generate them from the mask too but that's more general than it looks like you need here

Comment: @harold is there a way to do this without hard coding the `24` part? Can I somehow use an expression based on the value `x = 0x0F0000000`?

Comment: Yes start at `i = 0;`, then iterate `i = ((i | ~x) + 1) & x;` until `i` is back to zero

Answer (score 0):

I think this is closest to what you describe in the comment:

```
let x = 0x0F0000000
var offset = 0

while offset < 63 && (x & (1 << offset)) == 0 { offset += 1 }

for i in 0..<16 {
    let y = i << offset
    print(String(y, radix: 16))
}
```